# What is the exact rule for 12 months work permit find period after PhD study

Tags: visa, new-zealand

Does anybody know about the exact rules that a PhD student have work find permit period after studies? I need to know exactly how long after studies could someone stay for finding job? Another important question is how long should someone stay for studies inside New Zealand for getting that permit? I mean if someone get his PhD online outside of New Zealand but in NZ university due to the corona, can he apply for this type of visa or he should stay for example one year inside NZ to get that permission?

Comment: If you are currently a student there, you might be able to get an answer locally from the university. Even if you are in an application process, the university is likely to know these things.

Comment: This question is extraordinarily specific to one country.  Furthermore, other sites in the stackexchange network deal with immigration and visa issues.

Comment: You could try [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/tour), which deals with immigration and visa rules.

Answer (score 2):

New Zealand government offices are remarkably helpful and responsive. Almost strangely so. It's lovely and unexpected if you're used to services in other countries. Just contact Immigration NZ directly and ask. Don't entrust your important immigration advice to random Internet people.